# How to disable smooth tile transitions in Windows Phone?

Tags: live-tiles, performance

There is a feature in most Windows operating system (Desktop) that allow removal of transitions in favor of performance, such as disabling transitions, etc.

In Windows Phone, I am bothered by transitions that occur when going from an application to Start Menu or vice versa as I care most about speed not effects, effects like this.

[image]
[image]

I don't want Windows Phone to swap and turn live tiles beautifully around when switching between apps, rather, simply hide previous screen and show the new one. I prefer performance. Is there any way to disable such transitions in favor of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now animations cannot be turned if in Windows Phone and Windows Mobile. This is partly due to the fact that the time during those animations is required to load an app or the start screen. By masking loading times with movement on the screen the system actually feels faster than it actually is as you do not have a loading screen or an unresponsive phone for a second.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know a technical reasons might be behind the scenario :)

Comment: But, wouldn't those transitions add more overhead to the system, thus slowing the app startup?

Comment: I assume the animations are highly optimized to minimize the overhead so that the perceived performance boost is much greater than the actual slowdown.

Comment: @JasonStack, the entire phone UI (including the animations and other eye candy) are implemented using the GPU. The CPU barely needs to do anything except tell the GPU what animations to run, and can spend all its time on tasks like initializing the app you're launching. The GPU can't help with that part. It's one of the reasons WP's UI is so smooth even on low-end phones; the CPU is basically not used for graphics any more than it needs to be, and even low-end GPUs can handle the common UI tasks easily.